# Difference between Dynamic Factor Model and Factor Augmented VAR?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, dynamic-regression

One simple question:
What is the difference between the dynamic factor model and factor augmented vector autoregressive (FAVAR) model?

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Have you found an article using one model, another using the other and compared the sections that describe the models? That would be a reasonable way to go about it.

Comment: @RichardHardy [link](https://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~lchrist/course/Korea_2016/FAVAR_models_handout.pdf) this provides some insights but I couldn't figure out the main difference.